# PHP: Why is my cookie not being set correctly?

Tags: php, cookies

What's wrong with my code? When I run it, it tells me: "Notice: Undefined index: visits" on the lines `if($_COOKIE["visits"] == 1)` and `$numOfVisits = $_COOKIE["visits"];` in the body section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php 
if (!isset($_COOKIE["visits"])) 
    setcookie("visits", 1, time()+3600*24*365);
else{
    $visits = $_COOKIE["visits"] + 1;
    setcookie("visits",$visits, time()+3600*24*365);
}
?>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>numOfVisits</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if($_COOKIE["visits"] == 1)
            echo("Welcome to my webpage! It is your first time that you are here.");
        else{
            $numOfVisits = $_COOKIE["visits"];
            echo("Hello, this is the #$numOfVisits time that you are visiting my webpage.");
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: " Common Pitfalls:

    Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling print_r($_COOKIE);. " http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can only set cookies or start sessions before any headers are send from the server to the client. ([See documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) on `setcookie`)

> setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers. Like other headers, **cookies must be sent before any output from your script** (this is a protocol restriction). **This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including  and  tags as well as any whitespace.**

What this means in practise is that you can't set a cookie after you already output something. In this case you're outputting `<!doctype html>` before you are setting the cookie.

The solution is to set the cookie **before** you output any HTML.

So solution:

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_COOKIE["visits"])) 
    setcookie("visits", 1, time()+3600*24*365);
else{
    $visits = $_COOKIE["visits"] + 1;
    setcookie("visits",$visits, time()+3600*24*365);
}
?>
<!doctype html>
...
```

Comment: Oh I see. That simple! Thanks. It's my first assignment dealing with cookies. I did read that setcookie needed to appear before the html tag but I didn't realize that this included doctype.